# Modifying marker creation in android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

newbie here.

I am trying to make an app using google maps api. I know how to change a marker - color, picture, shape; I know how to display things on marker click like the city, lat, lang etc. The thing I couldn't find is how to create a marker that requires for you to fill in a customized form about the marker.

To make it easier to understand what I really want to do, here is the full explanation of my goal:

- user-admin is logged in and he can create a marker (*I created login/register part of my app already, no problems here :)* )
- when he long clicks on the map a new activity opens
- in that activity there are fields - admin name, restaurant name, short description and working hours
- there should be two buttons - if admin clicks **save** the marker is pinned and info is saved (server and sqlite), and if he clicks **cancel** it is never pinned

I have been looking for the answer for a while now without any success. I would appreciate if anyone has any idea how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: My code so far:

```
            //Add marker on long click
    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

        int iMax = 10; // Max number of markers one admin can pin

        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng arg0) {

            if (markerCount < iMax) {
                // start CreateRestautantActivity to open a form to fill
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CreateRestautantActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                markerCount = markerCount + 1;
                marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_create_restauranr))
                        .position(
                                new LatLng(arg0.latitude,
                                        arg0.longitude))
                        .visible(true));
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Only " + iMax + " markers allowed at the same time",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: what's the problem in this implementation?

Comment: Hi @Vivek, I tried opening a new activity from my mapsActivity, but it got really messy and realy went nowhere. I will add my code so far to show you this.

Comment: and what is the issue with your code?

Comment: Are you saying about, you want to let the admin input the details for the marker such as, lat, lng, restaurant name, description etc. And set this values in the marker. Is this correct?

Comment: yes, that's what he want

Comment: Well, on long click I open the activity, but I also get the marker pinned at the same time. As I said I am a newbie so i get lost fast. I was wondering should i do something like a yes/no popup window. I am also not sure how to connect the info to the restaurant.

Comment: @Vishnu I get lat lang on click, but yes, that is basically what I want. To add that to the marker and only when I click save marker should appear on the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can then do this in two ways. One is to open an activity by `startActivityForResult`, which will contain a form for inputting the required values such as RestaurantName, Description etc. After inputting the value and when user clicks OK, finish the activity and set the values as below:

`Intent mapViewIntent = new Intent();
    mapViewIntent.putExtra(MapActivity.KEY_RESTNAME, restaurantName);
    mapViewIntent.putExtra(MapActivity.KEY_DESCRIPTION, description);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, MapActivity);
    finish();`

Add these lines in your map activity.

`public static String KEY_RESTNAME = "restaurant_name";
public static String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";`

This will open your previous (map) activity and send back the data. You can get the restuarantName and description from onActivityResult() as follows:

`String restname = data.getExtra(KEY_RESTNAME);
String description = data.getExtra(KEY_DESCRIPTION)`.

Now you have restaurant name and description. And you know how to display these values in the marker.

Other way is similar to this, instead of opening an activity, you can use a dialog, which will contain the form for inputting the values.

Similarly you get other values too.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for not answering earlier I was bussy. Will try it in the morning and mark this as answered if it helps :) thanks for this man

Comment: I thought about doing this - after I create the marker, and when the app user clicks on the existing marker it should open the different activity that would have name, description, working hours, admin name, and also three buttons for grading the restaurant - positive, negative and neutral. Can this be achieved in the same way and do I need the KEYs for this. Thank you in advance :)